# Error when publishing a socket type object tcp (global)

Tags: javascript, sockets, events, tcp

first of all I want to apologize for my English, I hope you understand me.

The question I have is that I don't see the way to publish a socket type object to be able to be used from an interface, for example ajax or by means of events, etc.

```
'use strict';

const net = require('net');
const PORT = 5000;
const HOST = 'localhost';

class Server {
    //server = null;
    //socket = null;

    constructor(port, address) {
        this.port = port || PORT;
        this.address = address || HOST;
        this.server = net.createServer();
        this.socket = null;

        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        this.server.listen(this.port, this.address);

        this.server.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.socket.write(data);
        });

        this.server.on('close', () => {
            console.log('Cerrado');
        });

        this.server.on('error', (err) => {
            console.log('Error');
        });

        this.server.on('connection', function(sock) {
            console.log('Nuevo cliente conectado');
            this.socket = sock;
            //console.log(this.socket);
        });
    }

    prueba (accion) { 
        //console.log(this.socket); // null;
        this.socket.write(accion);
    }
}
module.exports = Server;
```

I await your response, thanks